# Read html and style tags content inside an html like php file?

Tags: php, file, file-read

I am trying to read all the css 'class' names and 'id' names used inside  tag in a php file which has  and  tags. I want to read all the class names and id names into an array. I am reading the file with 'fopen', file_get_contents and file methods but they are all not working properly. All I am getting the data as a webpage that is file content is showing as a webpage.

I am trying to read the below file

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<!-- Tekion related css -->
<style type="text/css">
    div.formThirdParty{
        width: 960px;
        min-height: 760px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: block;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://static.ed.edmunds-media.com/unversioned/libs/edw/edw-lib-0.0.2-min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/linkid.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-PQJ2GJZ&amp;l=CarCodeDataLayer"></script><script type="text/javascript">
    var tekion = {
      DEALER_ID: 5,
      TENANT_NAME: 'cacargroup'
    }
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/scheduling-buildfiles/tst/style.css" />

<title>INFINITI Service Dublin | Pleasanton</title>
<meta name="description" content="Schedule an oil change, tire rotation, brake replacement, or service inspection in Dublin for your INFINITI car or SUV. Get in touch with us at Dublin INFINITI." />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./infiniti_files/bundle_f7q.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .bg-color {
        background-color: ;
    }
    .hide-page-background
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    }

    .clickMapBlockTitle:after {
        background-image: url("http://media-dmg.assets-cdk.com/websites/5.0-353/websitesEar/websitesWebApp/common/images/spriteClickMap.png");
    }
```

---

My code is below:

```
$file_path = "/path/to/file/file_name.php";
$myfile = fopen($file_path, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Trial-1:

```
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
}
```

Trial-2:

```
$file_data = fread($myfile,filesize($file_path));
echo strip_tags($file_data,'<html><style>');
```

Trial-3:

```
$lines = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
print_r($lines);
```

All the output I am getting is a webpage but not the content. **My expected result** is only the content(like only class names and id names) inside 'style' tags after reading the total file. **The result** I am getting is if I try to echo the content after reading the data from the file is a webpage since the file has 'style' tags inside. Any help Please? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve]. What is the content of the PHP file? What result are you expecting? What result do you get?

Comment: @Quentin, Question updated. Sir, I already mentioned have mentioned What is the result that am expecting and what I got. But I updated the question once again.

Answer (score 0):

I used a preg_match_all to get all the style tags' contents:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file_path);

preg_match_all('/[<]style[^>]*[>]([^<]+)[<]\/style[>]/', $contents, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    var_dump($matches[1][$i][0]);
}
```

Comment: Did you try using my code snippet? Was it of any help? On my pc it extracted the 'style' tags' contents correctly